# Excel does not recognize C# function with DateTime arguments

Tags: c#, excel, add-in, excel-dna

I want to construct Excel addin with the following functions:

```
[ExcelFunction()]
public static  double myAverage1(double[] inputVector)
{
    return inputVector.Sum()/inputVector.Length ;
}

[ExcelFunction()] 
public static double myAverage2(DateTime[] TS1_DateTime) 
{
    return 12.5;
}
```

Problem is that Excel does not recognize function **myAverage2**.

The problem is related to the DateTime type, I tried to change it into String type but the function is strill not recognized. Any idea how to resolve this ?

What I eventually want to acheive is to give the function two DateTime arrays and get back the intersection of these.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/exceldna/pRwQnCaxEFI), Excel-DNA is supposed to automatically marshal `DateTime` values as `double` using [`ToOADate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx) and [`FromOADate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) methods.

I haven't tried it myself, but my guess is that it is not set up to detect arrays or lists of `DateTime`, but only single `DateTime` parameters.

Try declaring the parameter as `double[]`, and then within the function, do something like:

```
DateTime dt[] = values.Select(x => DateTime.FromOADate(x)).ToArray();
```

Or just call `FromOADate` on each value individually, depending on the needs of your function.

Despite the function being declared as a `double[]`, you should still be able to pass an array of cells containing dates, as Excel will want to pass them as OLE Automation Dates anyway.